# Setting system properties in Groovy

Tags: groovy, system-properties

**Please note:** Although I mention Swing and MacOS here, this question has nothing to do with either of them: I'm just providing them as a concrete example of what I'm trying to do.

---

I'm trying to set a system property the groovy way. If you are developing a Swing app on a Mac, it is common practice to set the following system property so that your Swing app's menu looks the same as typical Mac apps:

```
System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true")
```

When I call that inside my `main` method, it has the desired effect (the menu bar gets pulled off of the `JFrame` and is pinned to the top of the screen).

But when I go to try and make that call groovier:

```
System.properties['apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar', 'true']
```

it doesn't work. No exceptions, it just stops working and doesn't have the desired effect in the UI. **Why, and what can I do to fix it?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Should be:

```
System.properties['apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar'] = true
```

or

```
System.properties.'apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar' = true
```

In this piece of code:

```
System.properties['apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar', 'true']
```

`['apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar', 'true']` is taken as the key. See below:

```
def m = [ [1, 2,]:3, 2:4 ]
assert m[1, 2] == 3
```

The following piece of code returns correct results:

```
System.properties['lol'] = 2

assert 2 == System.properties['lol']
```

Comment: Or `System.properties.'apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar' = true`

Comment: @tim_yates, yes might be as well.

Comment: Thanks @Opal (+1) - interestingly enough, neither of these are working. They may very well be using valid Groovy syntax, but for some reason Swing (or Mac OS) is refusing to oblige them. By that, I mean the menus are not showing as "pinned"/docked to the top of the screen, independent of the JFrame/main window. But when I use standard Java-style syntax (using `setProperty(...)`) the menus *are* pinned/docked. Weird...

Comment: @smeeb, no idea why it does not work, but for sure the syntax you're using was incorrect.

Comment: Thanks again for the help; marking as correct, with the use case specific caveat that this particular Groovy syntax seems to have no effect on this particular sysprop on Macs for Swing development.

Comment: @smeeb, interesting. Maybe a good idea for an another question?