# clone git repository on my gradle using Grgit

Tags: java, git, svn, gradle

I have a gradle project which runs a script, and somewhere in it, I need to clone a git repository.
I had it running before with svn, but I change our company SCM to gitlab, and I need to change the code so it'll now clone the repo from git.

I need something that will work similar to this SVN code:

```
task exportLibs(type: SvnExport) {
  svnUrl = "http://<svn-url>"
  targetDir = "<target-dir-to-download-files>"
}
```

So I read about Grgit, but there was not a single example online, how to do a simple git clone (only this link http://ajoberstar.org/grgit/docs/groovydoc/org/ajoberstar/grgit/operation/CloneOp.html). If there is someone who can help me walkthrough this problem or maybe produced me to his grgit project so i will learn from it, it'll be awesome!

--Edit--

when i tried to use the grgit as below:

```
group 'test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
             url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.ajoberstar:gradle-git:1.7.2"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.ajoberstar.grgit'



org.ajoberstar.grgit.auth.hardcoded.allow=true
task pullFromGit{
    doLast {
        //grgit.pull()
    }
}


sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
     mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

i've use this properties to initial it, and i got the following error:

> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'grgit'.
>
> Could not get unknown property 'org' for root project 'grgit' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my code probably had some special imports in it, cause a the end the only clone that i could have done is shell exec.
the problem is solved, but not the bug i had...

Answer (score 3):

There is a link on the github page of the project to [some examples and the API documentation](http://ajoberstar.org/grgit/docs/groovydoc/index.html?org/ajoberstar/grgit/Grgit.html). The following snippet would solve your problem (in this case, it will clone the grgit project to the `grgit` directory)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.ajoberstar:grgit:1.7.2'
    }
}

task hello {
    doLast {
        org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.clone(dir: 'grgit', uri: 'https://github.com/ajoberstar/grgit.git')
    }
}
```

### Answer to the edited question

The [documentation](http://ajoberstar.org/grgit/docs/groovydoc/org/ajoberstar/grgit/auth/AuthConfig.html) states that `org.ajoberstar.grgit.auth.hardcoded.allow` is a system property. Your assignment is not a valid way to set system properties, see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36031930/setting-system-properties-in-groovy) for examples on setting system properties in groovy.